# PHPDocx log4php Configurator

Tags: php, docx, log4php, phpdocx

I am getting error while executing phpdocx create function. Although its working fine localy.

> Severity: Notice  --> Undefined index: log4php.threshold

Answer (score 1):

That is just a notice from `phpdocx`, maybe not all notices are solved, you can disable notices from production server.
Modify in `php.ini`:

```
error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE
```

Comment: You know you can disable debug? `$objDocx->fDisableDebug();`

Comment: still error throw after fDisableDebug() I get 505 error as well.

Comment: you could try adding in `.htaccess`: `php_flag display_errors off`

Answer (score 0):

The `undefined index` notice comes  when php script not finding matching index in array.

You have to check your array using `print_r($array)` or `var_dump($array)` whether it contains this index or not.